# UsedRange - can't eliminate trailing blank row

Tags: excel, vba

Both VBA and non-VBA answers accepted.

**Problem**

I'm trying to save a sheet as .csv using `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFilePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV`, but because the `UsedRange` includes a trailing blank row, I get an unwanted row of commas in the .csv.

**What I did immediately beforehand in the Code**

```
rngAllDate.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
```

This may be helpful if you're trying to recreate the issue.

**What I've Tried**

- Deleting all rows under my data
- Using the eraser tool to Clear All from all rows under my data
- Clearing formats from my entire worksheet, including my data, in case the borders were causing an issue
- Using the following VBA codeblock:

---

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    .UsedRange 'I'm told this recomputes the UsedRange
    MsgBox .UsedRange.Address

    Dim rngColumnsToDeleteAndClear As Range
    Set rngColumnsToDeleteAndClear = .Range(.Cells(1, WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(1)) + 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count))
    MsgBox rngColumnsToDeleteAndClear.Address
    rngColumnsToDeleteAndClear.EntireColumn.Clear
    rngColumnsToDeleteAndClear.EntireColumn.Delete

    Dim rngRowsToDeleteAndClear As Range
    Set rngRowsToDeleteAndClear = .Range(.Cells(WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(1)) + 1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
    MsgBox rngRowsToDeleteAndClear.Address
    rngRowsToDeleteAndClear.EntireRow.Clear
    rngRowsToDeleteAndClear.EntireRow.Delete

    .UsedRange
    MsgBox .UsedRange.Address
End With
```

---

I get the following Msgbox results from the above codeblock:

1. $A$1:$N$11
2. $O$1:$XFD$1
3. $A$11:$A$1048576
4. $A$1:$N$11

I expect the following Msgbox results from the above codeblock:

1. $A$1:$N$11
2. $O$1:$XFD$1
3. $A$11:$A$1048576
4. $A$1:$N$10

What else can I try?

Comment: Can't you use a filter and select anything but empty, copy range to new sheet and save as CSV?

Comment: What's the output of your other MsgBox calls?  I don't see any additional row in `UsedRange`

Comment: For the sake of asking, how consistent is your range?  if you know your number of columns (via dynamically determining last column) and you know your last row (via dynamically determining last row), you can use a specified range... cells(1,1).resize(lr,lc).copy or something like that

Comment: There are better ways to find the last row/column containing data.  `UsedRange` can have inaccuracies.  Do a `search` in this forum to find various methods.

Comment: Are you performing the CSV SaveAs using VBA?  If Yes, it would be useful to post that.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes I am - I've never used UsedRange before since I never need it as a VBA hound but that's how I understand VBA to know what to save. Here's my SaveAs line: `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFilePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV`

Comment: @Cyril Definitely agree with you - my problem is that I understand .SaveAs to use the `UsedRange` to determine output. Definitely don't have any problems copy-pasting or any other functions.

Comment: @TimWilliams Edited actual/expected results into question, cleaned up code block to make it easier to follow.

Comment: @TimWilliams Also added another detail that may help you recreate the issue - right before this happens, I do the following after filtering: `rngAllDate.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)`

Comment: What is your actual occupied range?

Comment: @TimWilliams $A$1:$N$10 (number 4 in expected Msgbox results)

Comment: I can't replicate what you're seeing.  UseRange is always A1:N10

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for trying!

Comment: Have you checked each cells on row 11 to make sure there are no spaces?

Comment: @W-hit Just did this, no spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the formatting of the actual data range was causing the UsedRange to include a blank row at the end. For the record, I was using a Thick Box Border around the data range.

After clearing formats from the data range as well, it *seemed* that the blank row was still being included in the UsedRange, as I stated I tested above, because when I pushed Ctrl-Shift-End, the highlighted area still included the blank row. However, VBA reveals that the actual UsedRange has in fact shrunk to row 10 from row 11.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had an issue with the UsedRange on a spreadsheet, and I couldn't delete/clear the cells and get the UsedRange to reset. The fix I found was to select all the un-used rows/columns, change the size of them, now delete the cells, save the spreadsheet, and boom the UsedRange was reset... Maybe this will help you?

Comment: Just tried this, unfortunately it didn't work for me, but I'm glad it worked for you and thank you for suggesting it! Sometimes inexplicable things do work.

Answer (score 0):

try running this to see if there are any hidden breaks on row 11 right before  you calculate that usedrange

```
Sub IterateCharacters()
    For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(11, 1), Cells(11, 14))
        With cell
            For n = 1 To Len(.Value)
                Debug.Print Asc(Mid(.Value, n, 1))
            Next n
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Also, try the line below right after you get the incorrect used range, then test the used range again.

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(11, 1), Cells(11, 14)).Replace "*", vbNullString
```